# Logging wireless access point connections

Tags: wireless, connection, log

Is there a way to find timestamps of when I connected/disconnected to wireless networks (so I can see where I was at some point in the past)? I can't seem to find any log files with this information (and my system doesn't seem to save logs older than about a month, anyway).

If no such log file exists, it possible to write a script that will do this for me?

Thanks!

P.S.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you have some scripting experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some last connections in

```
sudo less /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

But the timestamp is of the form

```
1293853087
```

To make it readable, you would use:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 +1293853087 seconds" 
Sa 1. Jan 03:38:07 CET 2011
```

For future use, it might be better to insert a few code lines to /etc/networks/ifup.d/YourScript

```
echo $(date) "  "$(if [ "$IFACE" = eth1 ]; then
    iwconfig | egrep -o "ESSID:*"
fi) >> /var/log/myip.log
```

or something similar.

I haven't done so, so there are surely some problems to solve. Maybe you don't have write access to /var/log/myip.log, and have to create it with `sudo touch ...` before, and allow some group (network?) to write to it.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately my /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ directory is empty? (Maybe I have some setting turned off?)

Comment: @jiangty: Do you use the NetworkManager?

Comment: Sorry for the late response; it at least appears that I use NetworkManager (it's the default way Ubuntu handles internet connection, correct?)

Comment: Yes, at least at 10.04, which I'm still using.